# SYBASE Table space information

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

Can any one help me finding the information of multiple tables in SYBASE. I Know in ORACLE we do Select * from USEr_segments;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar would be visible through running

```
select * from sysobjects where uid = user_id() and type = 'U'
```

Comment: It is  showing nothing...I am looking for something like this
 "call sp_iqtablesize ('dba.emp1')" but I need multiple table results at a single command

Comment: Please correct your question and write exactly what you want to have. You did not write explicitly what you wanted. I have written the answer for Sybase ASE.

Comment: I am agreeing with your answer but in that query I can not see the size of each table. I am more concerning about the size in that information. Please help me out to finding the size of multiple tables at a single result

Comment: So far, I  am using this query "call sp_iqtablesize ('dbo.valid0000')" which can only show single table result.